# Dynamically create a object array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, object, tuples

I need to add the parameters and the values to the following object dynamically. So far, I do it statically (hardcoded) by creating the object as follows:

```
object parameters = new { Param1 = UserNumber, Param2 = "201403", Param3 = true };
```

Then in the function, pass it as:

```
Helper.create(parameters);
```

^This works.

But, sometimes I just need to pass just one, none, or more than those three. The amount can change dynamically and not necessarily be named the same or it can be in a different order. So, I can't leave the name of the variables `Param1`, `Param2` and `Param3` statically. I also, don't control the behavior for the '`create()`' function.

I tried this (and more):

```
List<Tuple<object, object>> tupleList = new List<Tuple<object, object>>();

tupleList.Add(new Tuple<object, object>("Number", UserNumber));
tupleList.Add(new Tuple<object, object>("Start", 201403));
tupleList.Add(new Tuple<object, object>("Show", true));

object tuptest = tupleList.Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

But it creates it as one array with objects inside.
When you go step by step in the debugging, they show up differently than what I need.

The Documentation example is:

```
Helper.create( new { Parameter1 = "Text", Parameter2 = 1000 } );
```

How can I create this dynamically?

Comment: What is `create` expecting to receive?

Comment: do you have control over the create method? if so, maybe pass a dictionary in stead.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Please try to edit it so that someone other then yourself can understand it

Comment: edited to explain more

Answer (score 2):

Declare the method's signature using `params object[] args`, or a more specific type. This will allow you to pass any (or none) amount of parameters to the method, which you can then iterate inside the method.

E.g.:

`public void Foo(params Tuple<object, object>[] args)`

```
var a = new Tuple<object, object>("Number", UserNumber);
var b = tupleList.Add(new Tuple<object, object>("Start", 201403));
var c = tupleList.Add(new Tuple<object, object>("Show", true));
```

You'd then call it using `Foo(a, b, c);`

Answer (score 1):

Why not creating a whole new specific type?

```
public class UserParameters {
     public UserNumber Number { get; set; }
     public string Start { get; set; }
     public bool Show { get; set; }
}
```

This way, you have compile-time errors if you mistype anything, and also compile-time type checking. You don't have to cast your generic `object` arguments to any type, which was very error-prone.

Also, you can dynamically add or remove properties, so in a way you are adding or removing parameters.

The `create` method can accept this object, and you would call it like this:

```
parent.create(new UserParameters() {
     Number = Session.UserNumber,
     Start = "201403",
     Show = true
});
```

Any property that is `null` is a parameter you didn't pass or defined.

Comment: This won't work. I don't know the parameter names or types before hand.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an ExpandoObject & pass it to create

```
var x = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
            x.Add("Number", "UserNumber");
            x.Add("Start", 201403);
            x.Add("Show", true);
            Create(x);
```

Comment: This is going in the right direction. I now have 3 objects in an array.  But it creates a different type of object.  I added   `x = x.Cast<object>().ToArray();` but still I got 3 items.  Seems it is looking for just one line in the array.